# Replacements of multiple elements stored in a list

Tags: replacement

I think this problem is best described by just showing a short example:

```
(* Things I have *)
expr = x1*x2 + x3 + 5;
variables = {x1, x2, x3};
replacements = {5, 3 a, 8};

(* Is here a shorter way to do exactly this? *)
expr2 = expr /. Table[variables[[i]] -> replacements[[i]], {i, Length[variables]}]
```

The problem is, that *expr* can not in general be defined as a function, since it involves different numbers of variables (depending on the problem under consideration).

Comment: Try `expr /. Thread[ variables -> replacements ]`

Comment: If `expr` is not a function, what might it look like?  An equation?  If so, replacement should work just as well with it.  Then perhaps you need `Solve` to solve for an unknown after replacing?

Comment: That does the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @jjc385 could you type it in an answer. Then I can close the question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [`Thread`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Thread.html) to built a list of replacement rules:

```
rules = Thread[ variables -> replacements ]
```

> ```
> {x1 -> 5, x2 -> 3 a, x3 -> 8}
> ```

Then perform the replacement:

```
expr /. rules
```

> ```
> 13 + 15 a
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I don't really see why you think you cannot use a function.  Here is one easy way, using indexed variables.

```
expr[x_] := Indexed[x, 1]*Indexed[x, 2] + Indexed[x, 3] + 5
resolveExpression[expr_, replacements_] := Module[{x},
  expr[x] /. MapIndexed[Indexed[x, #2] -> #1 &, replacements]]
resolveExpression[expr, {5, 3 a, 8}]
```

Comment: The expression I am dealing with is a determinant of a partly symbolic matrix where the number of variables as well as the size of the matrix often changes. In principle, something like you showed should work but I am not sure if I mange to write the most general expression in terms of a function. But however, many thanks!